# How do i create pagination for my search results

Tags: php, html, search, mysqli, pagination

I'm trying to create **pagination** for my **search results**. I'm able to create a working pagination if I drop the search functionality (i.e by not including `if (isset($_POST['submit-search']))` and `LIKE %search%`) but once I include these, as seen in the code beneath, I only get a blank page when I click the next page, like as if the sql terms isn't kept in memory.

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
        $results_per_page = 2;      
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%$search%' OR a_text LIKE '%$search%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $number_of_pages = ceil($queryResult/$results_per_page);    

// determine which page number visitor is currently on   
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
       $page = 1;
    } else {
       $page = $_GET['page'];
    }

       $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE a_title LIKE '%$search%' OR a_text LIKE '%$search%'LIMIT ".$this_page_first_result.",".$results_per_page." ";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// echoing the search results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<h3>".$row['title']."</h3>
          <p>".$row['text']."</p>";
}

// echoing the pagination    
    for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
        echo "<li><a href='search_results.php?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>";  
    }   
        }
    ?>
```

html

```
<form action="search_results.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search"placeholder="Search">
        <button type="submit" name="submit-search">go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you stated the problem. Is the `search` value resubmitted as a POST when navigating to the next page? I've always made search stuff like this use GET. Addresses this problem and lets you share a link to your results, makes the request portable. If not submitting it again then you would need to use a session or something to persist that.

Comment: You are not posting when you goto the next page, its a simple url with only a page variable attached. So how is `$search` defined? It does not keep it in memory, correct. Perhaps store it in a user session or also as a get parameter.

Comment: And when you say "blank page" are you getting an error or just the table has no results?

Comment: Just no results ^

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong.

```
// this code is only executed on the initial search.
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
```

When the user go's to the next page:

```
echo "<li><a href='search_results.php?page=".$page."'>".$page."</a></li>";
```

Only a page number is given and the search parameter is lost as nothing is posted, so the first if statement will not run again.

You could do something like:

```
echo "<li><a href='search_results.php?page=".$page."&search=$search'>".$page."</a></li>";
```

And:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-search']) || isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search = ...;
}
```

Comment: When I click on a page I get a "Notice: Undefined index: search" on the $search line of code, and the page shows all results instead of the searched result, is this because I need to store the search term in a user session to keep it when I go through the pagination pages?